DataStage Oracle Connector doesn't execute 'After SQL statement'
I have a problem with an Oracle Connector. It should work as follows:
1 - Delete rows where the start date is equal to SYSDATE
2 - Insert data in that table
3 - Update rows with start date different from SYSDATE
I wrote the delete statement in "Before SQL statement" and it works. Step 2 works as well. The update statement in step 3 is written in "After SQL statement", but although the log says the command has been executed it has no effect on the table.
The UPDATE is as follows:
UPDATE table
SET end_date = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD') - 1,FLAG = 'N'

I tried to put the UPDATE and DELETE statements together,inside a BEGIN/END block, but then the job failed because it doesn't recognize the COMMIT statement after the block.
I tried to write the UPDATE statement just after the DELETE statement and before the COMMIT and it still has no effect on the table, while, again, the DELETE statement keeps working.
I also tried to execute both statements directly on the DB with SQL Developer and it worked. The only thing I know is that it's not a syntax problem.
Can someone help me?

Why can't you put a COMMIT inside the PL/SQL block?

TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD') can be simplified to TRUNC(SYSDATE)

Hello @MT0, I thought the COMMIT had to be put necessarily outside the BEGIN/END block. I put it inside the block and it worked. Thank you


I tried to put the UPDATE and DELETE statements together, inside a BEGIN/END block, but then the job failed because it doesn't recognize the COMMIT statement after the block.

Put the COMMIT statement inside the PL/SQL block.

Done, it worked. Thank you for your help!
